# Python Match Case: How can I match a case no matter if the letters are capitalized or not easily?

Tags: python, switch-statement, match

I have the next code (in Python):

```
lang = input("What's the programming language you want to learn? ").upper()

match lang:
    case "JavaScript".upper():
        print("You can become a web developer.")

    case "Python".upper():
        print("You can become a Data Scientist")

    case "PHP".upper():
        print("You can become a backend developer")
    
    case "Solidity".upper():
        print("You can become a Blockchain developer")

    case "Java".upper():
        print("You can become a mobile app developer")
    case _:
        print("The language doesn't matter, what matters is solving problems.")
```

I was just playing with it and I find it very useful, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
[Running] python -u "...\match.py"
  File "...\match.py", line 4
    case "JavaScript".upper():
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this a bug or how can I convert the conditions to uppercase that way without having to make a very large code?

I read the documentation and many things can be done, but I didn't find a solution to this or I didn't know how to see it.

**EDIT:**

In agreement with @Karl Knechtel, a possible solution for static cases could be the following:

```
lang = input("What's the programming language you want to learn? ").upper()

match lang:
    case "JAVASCRIPT":
        print("You can become a web developer.")

    case "PYTHON":
        print("You can become a Data Scientist")

    case "PHP":
        print("You can become a backend developer")

    case "SOLIDITY":
        print("You can become a Blockchain developer")

    case "JAVA":
        print("You can become a mobile app developer")
    case _:
        print("The language doesn't matter, what matters is solving problems.")
```

Comment: "how can I convert the conditions to uppercase that way" - why not just write them directly in uppercase, like `case "JAVASCRIPT":`? "without having to make a very large code?" - I can't understand the concern. For example, if you used the obvious `if` / `elif` / `else` structure, instead, like we had to do before Python 3.10, it should be the same number of lines of code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 's point is valid. But for the sake of learning did you check if there was a space or "," instead of "." between the string and the upper() function ?

Comment: Note that Python `match... case...` is not [tag:switch-statement], but [tag:pattern-matching]. They might look similar, and they do overlap, but they have different uses. Crucially, a pattern is not an expression, and can't be evaluated as one. As the dupe link says (and Karl Knechtel's comment as well), the closest thing Python has to a `switch` statement is still `if... elif... else`.

Comment: @Amadan Although remotely related, this question is not a duplicate to the question you link to. This question is about a syntax error resulting from an attempt to evaluate an expression in the `case` clause of a `match` statement, which is meant for either literal matching or type-based capturing. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Although there is no real code benefit as @Karl Knechtel
has pointed out, you can impose the pattern-matching by using a 'guard' expression: `case x if x == "Javascript".upper():` and so on. That said, `if-else` chain is to be preferred unless you are really pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python cannot evaluate an expression in the case bit, as you were trying to do. You could either have them all as uppercase to start with:

```py
lang = input("What's the programming language you want to learn? ").upper()

match lang:
    case "JAVASCRIPT":
        print("You can become a web developer.")

    case "PYTHON":
        print("You can become a Data Scientist")

    case "PHP":
        print("You can become a backend developer")

    case "SOLIDITY":
        print("You can become a Blockchain developer")

    case "JAVA":
        print("You can become a mobile app developer")
    case _:
        print("The language doesn't matter, what matters is solving problems.")
```

or, you could just use an if statement:

```py
lang = input("What's the programming language you want to learn? ").upper()

if lang == "JavaScript".upper():
    print("You can become a web developer.")

elif lang == "Python".upper():
    print("You can become a Data Scientist")

elif lang == "PHP".upper():
    print("You can become a backend developer")
    
elif lang == "Solidity".upper():
    print("You can become a Blockchain developer")

elif lang == "Java".upper():
    print("You can become a mobile app developer")
else:
    print("The language doesn't matter, what matters is solving problems.")
```

N.B. You may also want to remove leading/trailing whitespace or punctuation marks in `lang`. This is one way to do it.

```py
import string

lang = input("What's the programming language you want to learn? ")
lang = lang.upper().strip().strip(string.punctuation)
```